# How to add all integers to an array

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I am trying to add all numbers to an array list, I just have around 14 textboxes and all I want is to add up all the integerts in it. Here is code i am trying

```
int[] arr1 = new int[] { int.Parse(t1.Text), int.Parse(t2.Text), 
        int.Parse(t3.Text), int.Parse(t4.Text), int.Parse(t5.Text) };
```

Comment: Hint: use a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use linq:

```
int sum = arr1.Sum();
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a [`foreach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) loop.

```
int sum = 0;
foreach(int item in arr1)
{
    sum += item;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can select all the textboxes in your form and then sum them up using LINQ, something like:

```
int result = Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Sum(x => int.Parse(x.Text));
```

Note that this will throw an exception if `Parse` fails.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use linq:

```
var arr1 = new[] { t1, t2, t3, t4, t5 }.Select(x => int.Parse(x.Text)).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a LINQ expression like this.

```
int intArr[] = {2, 3, 4, 5};
List<int> intList = intArr.toList();
intList = intList.Sum();
intArr = intList.toArray();
```